# Using areas to evaluate the integral of $f(x) =-5x +(1-x^2)^{1/2}$ on the interval $[-1,0]$

Tags: calculus

> Use areas to evaluate the integral of $f(x) =-5x +(1-x^2)^{1/2}$ on the interval $[-1,0]$.

Comment: What have you tried? It is better to show some of your work so people can help you more

Answer (score 0):

This integral $I$ is sum of two areas $A_1$(triangle), $A_2$ (quarter of a circle of radius 1).
$$A_1=\frac{1}{2} 5(0--1)=5/2, ~~A_2= \frac{\pi}{4}.$$
Therefore, $I=5/2+\pi/4$